# Javascript regex starts with this or this

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating a regex for validating phone numbers. By now I have this:
`/^[+]\b\d{9,12}\b|\b\d{8,9}\b/`
it matches for every phone number that I know but it is missing one thing.
I want it to be true if I use: +351913456789 or 00351913456789.
How can I achieve the 00 part?

Comment: Make the `00` and `+` optional for the intro. `^(?:[+]|00)\d{9,12}`

Comment: Maybe it's a better idea to use google's libphonenum library, https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber. Successfully (and dependable) validating phonenumbers needs much more than the regex you have.

Comment: I didn't know that library! Starred!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the pipe `|` to match alternative patterns?

`^(?:[+]\b|00)\d{9,12}\b|\b\d{8,9}\b`

Comment: Maybe even `^(?:[+]\b|\b00)`?

Comment: `\b` match "word boundaries", in this case is not necessary because the `00` is at beginning of the string, so cannot be preceded by any word